# Возвращать тип в зависимости от реализации интерфейса без привязки класса к T

Tags: c#, множественное-наследование

Есть интерфейс

```
IInterface<T> 
{
  T prop {get;}
}
```

Есть так же 2 класса, которые его реализуют с разными типами (string, Stream)

```
class Class1 : IInterface<string> 
class Class2 : IInterface<Stream>
```

Так же есть 3ий класс, в котором есть метод возвращающий IInterface.

```
class Class3 
{
    IInterface<T> Method() { }
}
```

Можно ли как-то отвязаться от этой T в 3ем классе, чтобы метод возвращал просто IInterface, а тип T выбирался бы как-то внутри в зависимости от класса, который реализует тот самый IInterface (Если возможно, то без использования ап\down кастов )

Comment: нет, нельзя....

Comment: Ну, вы можете создать `IInterface`, от которого уже будет наследовать ваш `IInterface<T>`

Comment: @Monk, но у этого поля не будет `T prop {get;}` :)

Comment: `Можно ли как-то отвязаться от этой T в 3ем классе, чтобы метод возвращал просто IInterface` - у вас в коде нет интерфейса `IInterface`, а значит и вернуть его вы не можете, пока не добавите

Comment: @Grundy можно поизвращаться, сделать его `object` и дотипизировать. В наследнике =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно.

Но для того, чтобы вернуть правильный объект, ваш Class3 должен либо заранее знать тип T (например, он должен знать что это string) - либо должен получать его извне.

В первом случае надо так и писать - `IInterface<string>`:

```
IInterface<string> Method() { ... }
```

Во втором случае метод должен быть обобщенным (generic):

```
IInterface<T> Method<T>() { ... }
```

Третьего не дано.

Comment: Ну ещё в качестве варианта сам класс `Class3` должен быть обобщённым по `T`

Answer (score 1):

Строгая типизация возможна лишь тогда, когда вы не запуская программу уже заранее знаете какого типа будет объект, с которым вы в данный момент работаете. Например, если вы хотите обращаться к членам структуры Rectangle, необходимо явно объявить переменную этого типа (`Rectangle bounds;`, а не `object bounds`).

То же самое и с generic методом. Для того, чтобы иметь возможность использовать свойство `T IInterface<T>.Prop` без приведения типов (апкаст), необходимо будет заранее указать тип `T`.

В вашей модели такой подход не приемлем, потому что тип заказывает не пользователь API (`Class3.Method`). `Class3.Method` сам определяет, объект какого типа следует вернуть. А так как пользователь заранее не знает какого типа объект вернет `Method`, то подобный код не будет компилироваться:

```
interface IInterface { }
interface IInterface<T> : IInterface { .. }
class Class3 {
  IInterface Method() { .. }
}
// ..
IInterface itfs = class3Instance.Method();
var propVal = itfs.prop;
```

Даже если вынести в родительский интерфейс свойство `object prop`, вам все равно необходимо знать заранее тип объекта, который вернет это свойство, чтобы сделать приведение типов. Или перебирать все возможные варианты.

Чтобы выбраться из этой ловушки, необходимо изменить архитектуру классов, отталкиваясь от вашей задачи. Но это уже **новый вопрос**, отвечать на который в рамках этого вопроса нельзя. Плюс необходимо знать подробности задачи.